Flexible covariance structure of the nested term in linear mixed model
Linear mixed model with one grouping factor nested in the other is commonly specified as mod1 below, using the Oats data from the nlme package as an example:
library(nlme)
library(lme4)
library(sommer)


mod1 <- lme(yield ~ nitro, data = Oats, random = ~ 1 | Block/Variety )
summary(mod1)
# Linear mixed-effects model fit by REML
#   Data: Oats 
#        AIC      BIC    logLik
#   603.0418 614.2842 -296.5209

# Random effects:
#  Formula: ~1 | Block
#         (Intercept)
# StdDev:    14.50598

#  Formula: ~1 | Variety %in% Block
#         (Intercept) Residual
# StdDev:    11.00467 12.86696

There is one single estimate of the variance of Variety, which is 11.00467^2. This suggests that the specification random = ~ 1 | Block/Variety has an assumption that all levels of Variety has the same variance parameter. So I tried a more flexible modelling approach that allows me to explictly model all levels of Variety to have identical variance parameter in mod2:
mod2 <- lme(yield ~ nitro, data = Oats, random = list(Block = pdBlocked(list(pdIdent(~ 1), pdIdent(~ Variety - 1)))))
summary(mod2)
# Linear mixed-effects model fit by REML
#   Data: Oats 
#        AIC      BIC    logLik
#   603.0418 614.2842 -296.5209

# Random effects:
#  Composite Structure: Blocked

#  Block 1: (Intercept)
#  Formula: ~1 | Block
#         (Intercept)
# StdDev:    14.50598

#  Block 2: VarietyGolden Rain, VarietyMarvellous, VarietyVictory
#  Formula: ~Variety - 1 | Block
#  Structure: Multiple of an Identity
#         VarietyGolden Rain VarietyMarvellous VarietyVictory Residual
# StdDev:            11.0047           11.0047        11.0047 12.86695

As expected, variance parameters for Block and Variety are identical in mod1 and mod2.
I then try to relax the assumption by allowing for unequal variance parameter across levels of the Variety parameter in mod3a:
mod3a <- lme( yield ~ nitro, data = Oats, random = list(Block = pdBlocked(list(pdIdent(~ 1), pdDiag(~ Variety - 1)))))
summary(mod3a)
# Linear mixed-effects model fit by REML
#   Data: Oats 
#        AIC      BIC    logLik
#   605.1356 620.8751 -295.5678

# Random effects:
#  Composite Structure: Blocked

#  Block 1: (Intercept)
#  Formula: ~1 | Block
#         (Intercept)
# StdDev:    15.86869

#  Block 2: VarietyGolden Rain, VarietyMarvellous, VarietyVictory
#  Formula: ~Variety - 1 | Block
#  Structure: Diagonal
#         VarietyGolden Rain VarietyMarvellous VarietyVictory Residual
# StdDev:         0.00301314          14.15576        11.4053 12.82244

From mod3a, random-effects variance for VarietyGolden Rain, VarietyMarvellous, and VarietyVictory are 0.00301314^2 = 9.079013e-06, 14.15576^2 = 200.3855, and 11.4053^2 = 130.0809, respectively. The variance for the random-effects of Block is 15.86869^2 = 251.8153.
I then implement this same relaxed model in sommer package in mod3b:
mod3b <- mmer(yield ~ nitro, random = ~ Block + vsr(dsr(Variety), Block), rcov = ~ units, data = Oats, verbose = F)
summary(mod3b)
# ===============================================================
#            Multivariate Linear Mixed Model fit by REML           
# ************************  sommer 4.3  ************************ 
# ===============================================================
#         logLik        AIC      BIC Method Converge
# Value 2.398386 -0.7967714 3.756561     NR     TRUE
# ===============================================================
# Variance-Covariance components:
#                               VarComp VarCompSE Zratio Constraint
# Block.yield-yield               251.7    181.01  1.390   Positive
# Golden Rain:Block.yield-yield     0.0     75.29  0.000   Positive
# Marvellous:Block.yield-yield    200.3    161.24  1.242   Positive
# Victory:Block.yield-yield       130.2    125.16  1.040   Positive
# units.yield-yield               164.4     31.94  5.147   Positive

The estimates of variance parameter for Block and each level of Variety from mod3a and mod3b are identical highly similar, with the differences likely attributable to some trivial differences in technical details.
I then tried to further relax the assumption by allowing for covariance across levels of Variety in mod4a:
mod4a <- lme( yield ~ nitro, data = Oats, random = list(Block = pdBlocked(list(pdIdent(~ 1), pdSymm(~ Variety - 1)))))
summary(mod4a)
# Linear mixed-effects model fit by REML
#   Data: Oats 
#        AIC      BIC    logLik
#   609.2017 631.6866 -294.6008

# Random effects:
#  Composite Structure: Blocked

#  Block 1: (Intercept)
#  Formula: ~1 | Block
#         (Intercept)
# StdDev:    9.192434

#  Block 2: VarietyGolden Rain, VarietyMarvellous, VarietyVictory
#  Formula: ~Variety - 1 | Block
#  Structure: General positive-definite
#                    StdDev   Corr         
# VarietyGolden Rain 13.38741 VrtyGR VrtyMr
# VarietyMarvellous  12.17878 0.384        
# VarietyVictory     21.29399 0.941  0.335 
# Residual           12.86695

I also tried to implement (I think) the same model in lme4 (mod4b) and sommer (mod4c):
# In lme4:    
# mod4b <- lmer( yield ~ nitro + (Variety || Block), data = Oats)
# Or equivalently:
mod4b <- lmer( yield ~ nitro + (1 | Block) + (Variety - 1 | Block), data = Oats)
summary(mod4b)
# Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
# Formula: yield ~ nitro + (1 | Block) + (Variety - 1 | Block)
#    Data: Oats

# REML criterion at convergence: 589.2

# Scaled residuals: 
#      Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
# -1.69439 -0.73696 -0.06934  0.64163  1.74006 

# Random effects:
#  Groups   Name               Variance Std.Dev. Corr     
#  Block    (Intercept)        108.5    10.42             
#  Block.1  VarietyGolden Rain 155.2    12.46             
#           VarietyMarvellous  124.3    11.15    0.28     
#           VarietyVictory     429.4    20.72    0.95 0.27
#  Residual                    165.6    12.87             
# Number of obs: 72, groups:  Block, 6



# In sommer:
mod4c <- mmer(yield ~ nitro, random = ~ vsr(Block) + vsr(usr(Variety), Block), rcov = ~ units, data = Oats, verbose = F)
summary(mod4c)
# ==========================================================================
#                 Multivariate Linear Mixed Model fit by REML                
# *****************************  sommer 4.3  ***************************** 
# ==========================================================================
#         logLik       AIC      BIC Method Converge
# Value 3.365356 -2.730712 1.822621     NR     TRUE
# ==========================================================================
# Variance-Covariance components:
#                                          VarComp VarCompSE   Zratio Constraint
# u:Block.yield-yield                       221.35    152.05  1.45578   Positive
# Golden Rain:Block.yield-yield              42.25     98.74  0.42786   Positive
# Marvellous:Golden Rain:Block.yield-yield  -74.23     90.12 -0.82362   Unconstr
# Marvellous:Block.yield-yield               11.51    160.73  0.07158   Positive
# Victory:Golden Rain:Block.yield-yield     131.12    113.91  1.15116   Unconstr
# Victory:Marvellous:Block.yield-yield      -50.20    104.36 -0.48100   Unconstr
# Victory:Block.yield-yield                 316.25    233.06  1.35694   Positive
# units.yield-yield                         165.56     32.16  5.14772   Positive

Estimates of variance parameters from mod4a, mod4b, and mod4c are different. For example, the estimated variance of Block is 9.192434^2 = 84.50084 from mod4a, 108.5 from mod4b, and 221.35 from mod4c.
My questions are:

Why are mod4a from nlme and mod4b from lme4 different? Is it because the specified model is different or because technical differences in parameter estimation between the two packages?
mod4a is very similar to mod3a except for repalcing pdDiag(~ Variety - 1) with pdSymm(~ Variety - 1). mod4c is very similar to mod3b except for repalcing vsr(dsr(Variety), Block) with vsr(usr(Variety), Block). Why mod4a and mod4c are different whereas mod3a and mod3b are highly similar?

It is confusing that nlme, lme4, and sommer each give different result to what I belive the same model specification: unstructured covariance across levels of Variety and independent of Block.

Variety is not nested in Block. These factors are crossed in the Oats dataset, as we might expect from a designed agricultural experiment.
